# Oracle row count of table by count(*) vs NUM_ROWS from DBA_TABLES

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Looks like count(*) is slower than NUM_ROWS. Can experts in this area throw some light on this.

Comment: num_rows is a statistic that may not be up to date. if you need the actual count then you should go against the table itself with a count(*)

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I read somewhere that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - there was an extensive Ask Tom discussion about that that debunked that idea. it is the same.

Comment: [asktom thread thrashing out count(*) vs count(1) etc.](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245) for reference

Comment: I dont think count(1) and getting count from NUM_ROWS is the same

Comment: Should be moved to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: There's no need @FrostyZ, the OP is asking about the difference between selecting a single row from a system view and counting the number of rows in a table...

Comment: @Randy I found article about count(*) vs count(1) but not about NUM_ROWS. can you please provide the link for asktom discussion about the difference.

Comment: there's no article on asktom on NUM_ROWS vs count() as they are two non-comparable things. as you put in your answer, NUM_ROWS is just a statistic gathered at an earlier point in time and not a real-time answer (and NUM_ROWS may be null for a non-analyzed table)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2117.htm#REFRN20286) NUM_ROWS is the *"Number of rows in the table"*, so I can see how this might be confusing. There, however, is a major difference between these two methods.

This query selects the number of rows in MY_TABLE from a system view. This is data that Oracle has previously collected and stored.

```
select num_rows from all_tables where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

This query counts the current number of rows in MY_TABLE

```
select count(*) from my_table
```

By definition they are difference pieces of data. There are two additional pieces of information you need about NUM_ROWS.

1. In the documentation there's an asterisk by the column name, which leads to this note:

   > Columns marked with an asterisk (*) are populated only if you collect
   >   statistics on the table with the ANALYZE statement or the DBMS_STATS
   >   package.

   This means that unless you have gathered statistics on the table then this column will not have any data.
2. Statistics gathered in 11g+ with the default `estimate_percent`, or with a 100% estimate,  will return an accurate number for that point in time.  But statistics gathered before 11g, or with a custom `estimate_percent` less than 100%, uses dynamic sampling and may be incorrect.  If you gather 99.999% a single row may be missed, which in turn means that the answer you get is incorrect.

If your table is *never* updated then it is certainly possible to use ALL_TABLES.NUM_ROWS to find out the number of rows in a table. **However**, and it's a big however, if any process inserts or deletes rows from your table it will be at best a good approximation and depending on whether your database gathers statistics automatically could be horribly wrong.

Generally speaking, it is always better to actually count the number of rows in the table rather then relying on the system tables.