# how to get count(*) from an oracle view having large number of records

Tags: sql, oracle

Please let me know how can we to select count(*) from an oracle view faster when having large number of records, preferably using predefined tables like ALL_TABLES.

Comment: You want to count the number of records faster than `count(*)` does it? All you can do is... count then. Were you hoping for something like the value you can get from `all_tables.num_rows`, which is only accurate (at best) at the point statistics are gathered? Unless you have a materialised view that number doesn't exist. Maybe you need to tune the query the view is using.

Comment: Following up on Alex's comment: You may use something like `all_tables.num_rows`, if you gather statistics often enough, if the number of rows in the table NEVER varies rapidly, and if you only need a very rough estimate of the number of rows. It all depends very strongly on your needs and your specific situation.

Comment: @mathguy - and if the OP was asking about a table, not a view... But for tables, yes, agree. The main thing is realising it's going to be a rough guide unless the data is static - useful for order of magnitude but not much else really. (Also just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14125731/266304).

Comment: An index on a small, not-null field might help a bit, though

Comment: @ammoQ  ... UNIQUE index ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faster alternative in Oracle to SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM sometable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840538/faster-alternative-in-oracle-to-select-count-from-sometable)

Comment: @Mottor: sure? For counting, it shouldn't make a difference if the index is unique or not. It's just important that the column is not nullable.

Comment: @ammoQ Sorry. NOT NULL is enough. Where is my coffee?