# How to get the exact row count without using count(*)?

Tags: oracle

How can we get the exact count per Oracle table without `count(*)` for each table?

I know the question has been asked before, but with technological advancements, I wondered if there's some more optimized and fast process available.

Comment: If you want to know the exact number of rows in a table, `select count(*)... ` is the way to go.

Comment: Just curious, how are you going to use that information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14125731/1509264

Comment: The only way you can get an answer with less work is to rely upon the value stored in the data dictionary as the result of analyzing a table. Of course, the value stored could only be an estimate. And, of course, the value stored becomes less accurate over time as rows are added and removed after the most recent analyze.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle row count of table by count(\*) vs NUM\_ROWS from DBA\_TABLES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125731/oracle-row-count-of-table-by-count-vs-num-rows-from-dba-tables)

Answer (score 0):

1. Tell whomever asked you not to use the `COUNT` function not to be silly and just use the function that was designed for that job.
2. Gather statistics on the table and then use:

   ```sql
   SELECT num_rows FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE';
   ```

   *Note: If you do not have any statistics on the table then the column will not be populated and if the statistics are not up-to-date (or are based on a partial sample of the rows) then you will get the wrong answer.*
3. Create a user-defined function to select from all the rows into a collection and then return the size of the collection.
4. Create a user-defined function to select from all the rows into a cursor and then loop through the results set counting the rows manually and return the size of the cursor.
5. Use another way of counting like:

   - `SELECT MAX(ROWNUM) FROM table_name;` or
   - `SELECT SUM(1) FROM table_name;`
6. Use `SELECT count(*) * 100 FROM table_name SAMPLE BLOCK (1);` to estimate the number of rows (yes, this uses `COUNT` but you could use one of the other methods in its place. It is also only an estimate).

Apart from using `COUNT()`, most of these will either only give estimates (and have the potential to be inaccurate) or will be slower than using `COUNT` so just use `COUNT`.

---

> I thought If some more optimized and computationally fast process available.

No, there is not. If there was then it would have been used in the implementation of the `COUNT` function.